# WCF Data Service stored procedure returns strange string value

Tags: wcf, dataservice

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestDataSP]
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName 
    FROM Employees 
    WHERE EmployeeID = 7
END
```

TaskTrackerDataService.cs

```
[WebGet]
public String GetEmployeeName()
{
    TaskTracker_EDM.TaskTrackerEntities ctx = new TaskTracker_EDM.TaskTrackerEntities();
    return ctx.TestDataSP().FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

I have a stored procedure, I can call it from Web

```
http:localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc/GetEmployeeName
```

it will return the Employee name

```
<GetEmployeeName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">Keko88</GetEmployeeName>
```

When I try to call the stored procedure from the my WPF project

```
TaskTrackerDataService.TaskTrackerEntities ctxDSvc =  new TaskTrackerDataService.TaskTrackerEntities(new Uri("http:localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc"));

String emps1 = ctxDSvc.Execute<String>(new Uri("http:localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc/GetEmployeeName")).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID: {0} ==== ==== ====  ", emps1));
```

it always returns

```
"System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse`1[System.String]"
```

Any help, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was 
always return "System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse`1[System.String]"

so add single and it will return the string result right

String emps1 = ctxDSvc.Execute(new Uri("http:localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc/GetEmployeeName")).Single();

the wrong one was 
String emps1 = ctxDSvc.Execute(new Uri("http:localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc/GetEmployeeName")).ToString();